# probability of an event question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

Find the probability of the event $B= \{\text{NO two people are born in the same month}\}$. There are 9 people involved by the way.
Is it 
$$
1/12 \cdot 1/11 \cdot 1/10 \cdot 1/9 \cdot 1/8 \cdot 1/7 \cdot 1/6 \cdot 1/5 \cdot 1/4 \cdot 1/3 \cdot 1/2 \cdot 1/1\,? 
$$

Because the first person has $1/12$ of it being any month and then the next person only has $1/11$ because 1 month was taken out so they are not on the same month... etc

Comment: How does your solution change if we consider 10 people?

Comment: i just thought of that... so should i only decrement up to 9?  1/12 * 1/11 * 1/10 * 1/9 * 1/8 * 1/7 * 1/6 * 1/5 * 1/4? But that doesn't make sense because what if we have 15 people... but then it wouldn't be possible because there are only 12 months so some people would have to share a month. Can we use exclusion/inclusion for this by the way?

Comment: http://imgur.com/vB9B5?tags.

Comment: LOL.... thanks.

Comment: @WalterWhite I hereby request you kindly but also urgently to restrict to comments from wich you are sure that nobody will dislike them. The (second) comment you give here is not an example of that.

Comment: I thought it was hilarious, the only problem i could see is if the link ever goes down people might not see the reply or maybe they dont want to click it. Maybe add words to your reply just in case.

Comment: @drhab [duly noted](http://assets0.ordienetworks.com/misc/tumblr_m2e5nmJaf41rqr258o1_500.gif)